# Minimal example to compile & run assembly with gcc?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  return 0;
}
```

what's the shortest assembly example to do the same that can be compiled into an executable by gcc?

I came across [this example](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~bjorn/CS200/linux_tutorial/) but there're too many tags like `hi_temp:,.data` etc,what's the minimal version?

Comment: What CPU (family), OS, etc ? And is it supposed to output "Hello world!" or not ?

Comment: And what about output ? The canonical "Hello world" program actually outputs that text.

Comment: @Paul R ,just `return 1` is enough(`movq $1 %rax`),I want to know the minimal version(with minimal tags) of a complete assembly.

Comment: OK in that case you should probably remove the reference to "hello world" from your question in order to avoid confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.text
    .align 4
    .globl main
main:
     pushl %ebp
     movl %esp,%ebp
     xorl %eax,%eax
     leave
     ret
```

To compile and run:

```
$ gcc -m32 asm.S
$ ./a.out
```

Comment: `gcc minimal.S` fails. `undefined reference to `main'`

Comment: You need `-m32 -nostdlib` - I'll update the answer with a version which is simpler to build and run

Comment: R ,it's very near,and it also works if you remove the `.align 4` line.

Comment: He did say `return 0`.  Add `xorl %eax,%eax`?

Comment: It is not minimal, as it fools around with the stack frame, which is not needed here.

Comment: This also uses the stdlib implicitly

Answer (score 3):

```
.text
    .globl main
main:
     xorl %eax,%eax ;return 0
     ret
```

Comment: is the indent before `.globl main` necessary?

Comment: No, indentation is just personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of Hello World in assembly, along with an explanation:

http://asm.sourceforge.net/intro/hello.html